# Docker, rabbitMQ and pike connection refused

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, pika

I am trying to connect to rabbitMQ from inside docker, using docker-compose. There are no problems connecting to the "image: rabbitmq:3-management" from a program running outside the container.

There are no passwords set or anything.

After looking a bit more at the error message it seems like pika tries to connect with IPv6 instead of IPv4. Looking at the documentation I can't figure out a way to connect with IPv4.

Failure happens on

```
self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))

Error log
rabbitMQ_1  | 2020-12-09 12:41:42.332 [info] <0.685.0> Ready to start client connection listeners
rabbitMQ_1  | 2020-12-09 12:41:42.333 [info] <0.988.0> started TCP listener on [::]:5672
listener_1  | ERROR:pika.adapters.utils.io_services_utils:Socket failed to connect: <socket.socket fd=9, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 36782)>; error=111 (Connection refused)
listener_1  | ERROR:pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow:TCP Connection attempt failed: ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused'); dest=(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, 6, '', ('127.0.0.1', 5672))
listener_1  | ERROR:pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow:AMQPConnector - reporting failure: AMQPConnectorSocketConnectError: ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused')
listener_1  | ERROR:pika.adapters.utils.io_services_utils:<socket.socket fd=9, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET6, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6, laddr=('::', 0, 0, 0)>.connect(('::1', 5672, 0, 0)) failed: OSError(99, 'Cannot assign requested address')
listener_1  | ERROR:pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow:TCP Connection attempt failed: OSError(99, 'Cannot assign requested address'); dest=(<AddressFamily.AF_INET6: 10>, <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, 6, '', ('::1', 5672, 0, 0))
listener_1  | ERROR:pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow:AMQPConnector - reporting failure: AMQPConnectorSocketConnectError: OSError(99, 'Cannot assign requested address')
listener_1  | ERROR:pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow:AMQP connection workflow failed: AMQPConnectionWorkflowFailed: 2 exceptions in all; last exception - AMQPConnectorSocketConnectError: OSError(99, 'Cannot assign requested address'); first exception - AMQPConnectorSocketConnectError: ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused').
listener_1  | ERROR:pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow:AMQPConnectionWorkflow - reporting failure: AMQPConnectionWorkflowFailed: 2 exceptions in all; last exception - AMQPConnectorSocketConnectError: OSError(99, 'Cannot assign requested address'); first exception - AMQPConnectorSocketConnectError: ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused')
listener_1  | ERROR:pika.adapters.blocking_connection:Connection workflow failed: AMQPConnectionWorkflowFailed: 2 exceptions in all; last exception - AMQPConnectorSocketConnectError: OSError(99, 'Cannot assign requested address'); first exception - AMQPConnectorSocketConnectError: ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused')
listener_1  | ERROR:pika.adapters.blocking_connection:Error in _create_connection().
listener_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
listener_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 450, in _create_connection
listener_1  |     raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
listener_1  | pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services: 
  rabbitMQ:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
  login:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.login
    restart: on-failure
  listener:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.listener
    restart: on-failure
```

Comment: How do you configure the location of the RabbitMQ broker?  `localhost` in Docker usually means "this container", not another container or the outside host; [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes the overall network environment you have available to you.

Answer (score 7):

The docker-compose does not setup a localhost network. This means that each service has their own name.

In this case the host should be changed from:

```
self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
```

to:

```
self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='rabbitMQ'))
```